# Gatsby Unable to process image from markdown files

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am revamping a blog to Gatsby which is lightning fast, everything seems perfect but I am facing different sort of issue, as the images I have via Netlify CMS aren't appearing properly in the blog, the images are appearing blur. I don't know what is going wrong here.

Here is the example of the problem statement

[DEMO](https://bhavikji.com/blog/backpacking-in-arunachal-pradesh-part-1)

here is the excerpt of my gatsby-config.js.

```
plugins: [
        `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
        `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms`,
        {
          resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
          options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/static/home`,
            name: 'home',
          },
        },
        {
          resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
          options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/static/blogs`,
            name: 'blogs',
          },
        },
        {
          resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
          options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/static/author`,
            name: 'author',
          },
        },
        {
          resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
          options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/static/svg`,
            name: 'svg',
          },
        },
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
            options: {
                path: `${__dirname}/content`,
                name: 'pages',
            },
        },
        {
          resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
          options: {
            path: `${__dirname}/content`,
            name: 'blog',
          },
        },
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
            options: {
                name: 'assets',
                path: `${__dirname}/static`,
            },
        },
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Bhavikji",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Bhavikji website",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "author": "Oscar",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.5.3",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "disqus-react": "^1.0.7",
    "gatsby": "^2.18.12",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.34",
    "gatsby-paginate": "^1.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "^2.1.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.1.34",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.31",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.1.30",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "^4.1.33",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.30",
    "gatsby-plugin-optimize-svgs": "^1.0.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-prefetch-google-fonts": "^1.4.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.26",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.3.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.26",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "^2.1.22",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.1.35",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.1.39",
    "gatsby-remark-lazy-load": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-remark-normalize-paths": "^1.0.0",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.3.29",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^0.2.3",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^2.2.31",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^2.1.19",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.40",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.45",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.7",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "netlify-cms-app": "^2.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.18.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-clamp-lines": "^3.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "sharethis-reactjs": "^1.5.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.7.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.7.4",
    "autoprefixer": "9.7.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "0.2.26",
    "browserslist": "4.8.2",
    "concurrently": "5.0.2",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "14.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "23.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.17.0",
    "eslint-watch": "6.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "rimraf": "3.0.0",
    "stylelint": "12.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "4.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.13.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1",
    "lint:js": "eslint --cache --ext .js,.jsx .",
    "lint:scss": "stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\"",
    "lint": "concurrently \"yarn run lint:js\" \"npm run lint:scss\" \"yarn flow\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

config.yml

```
media_folder: static/blogs
public_folder: blogs

collections:
- name: blog
  label: Blog
  folder: "content/blog"
  create: true
```

Here is the repository link for the DEMO and reproduction of the issue
[**REPO LINK**](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22488)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am more interested in how do you call those images in your components rather than in the `package.json` (it doesn't seem a dependencies issue) because inspecting the code, it seems that you've added the `/static` path which is not required. As it is shown in the following screenshot:
[image]

Regarding the updates coming from the comments below, we've figured out that the issue is related directly to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22488) where apparently images retrieved by a markdown are blurring. What solves the issue is to pass a `withWebp` parameter in Gatsby's configuration, so in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
    options: {
      maxWidth: 1920,
      withWebp: true,
    },
  },
```

Thanks to @Mr. Pyramid for the patience.

Comment: Since the data is from markdown files therefore, it is loading with as HTML via dagnerouslyLoadHTML.

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid have you found the solution? As far as I know, you only need to set a value via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` when you print a raw HTML, something like rich text from any CMS, markdown preformatted files, etc. In this case, the issue seems related to routes and paths.

Comment: No I haven't found it, yes I am using Netlify CMS, for the content.

Comment: The concept is, if your CMS field is a `string` type you can access it via `useStaticQuery` o graphQL query in your component. If it comes from a `richText` or `markdown` type, you should print it using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (because you are printing everything coming from that rich text). Let me know because I will update my answer if needed.

Comment: Yes I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to print out whatever coming from Rich Text. I can see the difference here that I don't have srcset here in the image object. But I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210152/discussion-between-mr-pyramid-and-ferran-buireu).